# Hitman: Codename 47 "No render is selected"

Tags: steam, hitman-codename-47

I recently bought Hitman: Codename 47 from Steam. When I try to run it, this message comes up:[image]

I tried different stuff like:
[image]

And:

[image]

After a while with a lot of changing random settings that don't work, this was my closest result to playing the game :/

[image]

*Direct3D Error: Unable to find suitable display mode for true color. Try 16 Bit color*

Comment: Can you do a Dxdiag (remove all relevant information that could identify you or your computer as-well) ? Also When you right click the game in your steam library, the options / settings is there check integrity? What screen size, and how many bit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the hitman.ini file, located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Hitman Codename 47), and make sure you have the file like this:

```
Include Setup\Locale.zip
//DrawDll Render3DFX.dll
DrawDll Renderd3d.dll
//DrawDll RenderOpenGL.dll
SoundDll Sound.dll
ScriptDll GSC.dll
LocaleDLL Locale.dll
Resolution 800x600
ColorDepth 32
Anisotropy 2
ShadowDetail 2
TextureResolution 0
DisableLight
enableconsole 1
Window
```

Because you have this issue the fix is to play it in windowed mode, which I enabled by adding **Window** at the end. Also, you can increase the resolution located at the **Resolution** line (the maximum is 1600x1200 but you can increase it to any number you want).

Side note: Hitman 47, looks better in OpenGL, to enable it, remove the slashes on the fourth line, and add two slashes to the third line.

If the window doesn't appear (the cursor may look like trapped) press Windows+D, wait 10 seconds or so and on the taskbar click the app that says Direct3D.

*Of course, this is for Windows :)*

Comment: I couldn't find the .ini file. :(

Comment: Nvm, got it. The game works but it's bad with 2 screens. Thanks though :)